# separable differential equation $(x^2+1)dy=-xy\,dx$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Hi guys we have been tasked to find if the equation is separable.

$$(x^2+1)\frac{dy}{dx}=-xy$$

This is what I have got so far,

$$(x^2+1)dy=-xy\,dx$$

$$\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{-x}{x^2+1}\,dx.$$

I am having a bit of trouble with the intergration.
Any hint/help or suggestions will be really help full
Cheers Robert

Answer (score 0):

If the problem only asks if the ODE is separable, then you are done. You separated it. But if you really need to solve it, the left side integrates to $$\ln|y|$$ For the right side, try the *substitution* $u=x^2$.

Comment: Awsome thanks for the heads up mate. Ill give it a crack now.